# Any introductory review for renormalization group and machine learning?

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations, renormalization, computational-physics, effective-field-theory

There seems to be some relationship between RG and machine learning. See, for example, https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.3831  .

Are there any review or books for this subject? Or, in general, are there any review on the relationship between RG and computer science related subject? My background is mainly on high energy physics, so any introduction of RG in complex system will also help.

Comment: Try to look onto MERA, multi-scale entanglement renormalization ansatz